# FFmpeg: create a video from a list of images, where each images stay N frames

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to create a video from a list of images, in such a way that the final video should be 24fps, but each image should stay during 3 frames before showing the next image (and I don't want to change the fps, I really need 3 identical frames).

For now I'm using:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 24 -pattern_type glob -i "build/*.jpg" "$@"
```

but each image stays only one frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to combine the input and output frame rates to achieve this:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 8 -pattern_type glob -i "build/*.jpg" -r 24 "$@"
```

The input `-framerate 8` sets to show each image for 1/8=0.125 seconds, and output `-r 24` sets the output framerate to be 24 fps and use each input frame for 24/8=3 output frames.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Note that position of the `-r 24` is important: I tried to add it after the last parameter, and it was not working.

Comment: Correct. I wasn't sure what "$@" is but I assumed it is a variable for your output url.

Comment: This command is written in a makefile, so the "$@" corresponds to the output (sorry, I forgot to accept).